# Domain Name Server Host for IBM cloud applications?

Tags: dns, twilio, ibm-cloud, sendgrid

I have my applications deployed in `IBM cloud`. Moreover, I am using `Send Grid` services in my application. So I want to enable domain authentication in Send Grid to send mails efficiently.

But I am not able to figure out the DNS host for IBM cloud. The following below DNS options are provided by Send Grid:

```
123Reg
Alibaba Cloud
Amazon Route 53
Cloudfare
ClouDNS
CSC Corporate Domains
GoDaddy
Google Cloud
```

and many more. I found in Google that IBM domain is `www.softlayer.net` but in my IBM console I am not able to configure the DNS. Any help?

Comment: Are you using this version of Sendgrid? https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/infrastructure/email-delivery

Comment: No henrik, I am using Send Grid API keys in my application to access the Email services not the IBM provided Email service.